# PHP cannot autoload classes

Tags: php, classloader, autoload

We used to include only classes that are stored in a `{project_root}/includes` folder. And we used autoload function to include classes we need in our apps. Now I wanted to use some library and I faced a problem:

1) Autoload:

```
// {project_root}/includes/autoLoad.php
// There is a global_connfig.php file that loads by directive in php.ini 
// auto_prepend_file = /var/www/global_config.php which includes autoload.php file and sets the include path to {project_root}/includes
function __autoload($classname){
    include "$classname.php";
}
```

2) Code I wanted to use:

```
//just an example from the monolog reference
// I put Monolog folder with it's subfolders in {project_root}/includes
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$log = new Logger("name");
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(LOGSPATH . '/monolog', Logger::WARNING));


$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

3) Errors:

```
Warning: include(Monolog\Logger.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
directory in {project_root}/includes/autoLoad.php
```

I tried to use something like this: [autoloading classes in subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499387/autoloading-classes-in-subfolders), but still getting
`Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found`

**question updated**

Comment: Where is your autoload function registered ? Did you try "include _ _ DIR _ _."/$classname.php"; ?

Comment: In the Code you want to use, where do you include the includes/autoLoad.php ?

Comment: Do you have the Monolog\Logger class somewhere in your include_path ?

Comment: @Thibault Thanks. I edited question)

Comment: @Thibault There is a global_connfig.php file that loads by directive in `php.ini auto_prepend_file = /var/www/global_config.php which includes autoload.php file`

Comment: Yes I saw your update. But where is the actual Monolog\Logger.php file ?

Comment: @Thibault Oh, I forgot this also... I put it in {project_root}/includes folder (there is a Monolog folder with subfolders with classes it needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this autoload function instead :

```
function __autoload($classname)
{                                      
    $filename = str_replace("\\", "/", $classname).".php";       
    include __DIR__."/$filename";                                     
}
```

- It replaces `\` with `/` to match paths
- It searches from the `includes/` directory.

You might also consider adding the `includes/` path to your `include_path` php directive :

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "{project_root}/includes");
```

Comment: Woww, that look to remove error I got! Now it's just `Warning: include{project_root}/includes/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php): ` But this is inside a Monolog, so now it founds Monolog. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for `preg_replace()` here. `str_replace()` will do the job as well and is much faster. I would also recommend using `spl_autoload_register()` instead of `__autoload()`.

Comment: While trying it I had the same error. It's because Monolog depends on Psr. See the composer.json from Monolog. You will need Psr. Or use composer to include Monolog and its dependencies, it will help a lot.

Comment: @simon I switched to str_replace. Thanks. I let the OP decide wether she wants to use spl_autoload_register() or keep __autoload()