# how to use the namespace classes in php

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I have a class with namespace which require many other classes further . main class is

```
<?php
/**
 * Deals with PDF document level aspects.
 */
namespace Aspose\Cloud\Pdf;

use Aspose\Cloud\Common\AsposeApp;
use Aspose\Cloud\Common\Product;
use Aspose\Cloud\Common\Utils;
use Aspose\Cloud\Event\SplitPageEvent;
use Aspose\Cloud\Exception\AsposeCloudException as Exception;
use Aspose\Cloud\Storage\Folder;

class Document
{

    public $fileName = '';

    public function __construct($fileName='')
    {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the page count of the specified PDF document.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
     public function getFormFields()
    {
        //build URI
        $strURI = Product::$baseProductUri . '/pdf/' . $this->getFileName() . '/fields';

        //sign URI
        $signedURI = Utils::sign($strURI);

        //get response stream
        $responseStream = Utils::ProcessCommand($signedURI, 'GET', '');

        $json = json_decode($responseStream);

        return $json->Fields->List;
    }
}
```

I am using this like this in index.php

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
use Aspose\Cloud\Pdf;

$document=new Document;
echo $document->GetFormFields();

//or like this 
echo Document::GetFormFields();

//also tried this 
echo pdf::GetFormFields();

?>
```

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Document' not found in /var/www/pdfparser/asposetry/index.php on line 5
```

Document class path is **Aspose/Cloud/Pdf/Document.php**

**attempt one**

working if i use to include in index.php `include(Aspose/Cloud/Pdf/Document.php)` but then further namespace produce error. Very difficult to change every `use` namespace with `include`. can anybudy tell me the solution for this ??

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace Aspose\Cloud\Pdf;

class Document {
    ...
```

To `use` this class, you'll have to write

```
use Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document
```

You can also access it without a `use` statement, but then you'll have to write the full name every time:

```
$document=new Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document;

// Or if you're in a namespace, you'll have to do this:

$document=new \Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document' not found in /var/www/pdfparser/asposetry/index.php on line 5 is the error

Comment: @ris You'll either have to `include` each class file, or define an autoloader to do it for you. Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `Document` class that's inside the `Aspose\Cloud\Pdf` namespace, but you are actually using a `Document` class without a namespace. You have to use one of the following ways:

```
//Option one:
use Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document;
Document::getFormFields();

//Option two:
Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document::getFormFields();
```

Also note that you can't use `Document::getFormFields()` as a static function, because it is not static. You should make it static (by putting `static` between `public` and `function`) or use it on an object.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Document' not found in /var/www/pdfparser/asposetry/index.php on line 5 error

Comment: You probably forgot to actually include the file with the Document class somewhere in your application. Use autoload or inlcude the file manually: `include('Aspose/Cloud/Pdf/Document.php');`

Comment: now error move to next class. i have to include classess in every class??? this is the error now Fatal error: Class 'Aspose\Cloud\Pdf\Product' not found in /var/www/pdfparser/asposetry/Aspose/Cloud/Pdf/Document.php on line 365

Comment: maybe you should consider some autoloader for loading your classes automatically? Standard PHp http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Yes, you'll either have to include each class seperately (though only once in your application) or use an autoloader as @AdamM suggests. An autoloader checks whether you've already loaded (included) a class when you're using one. If not, it will include it for you.

Comment: where can i define __autoload function ?? i have defiend in index.php still same errors

Comment: Using an autoloader is not that simple when your classes are located in different folders. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9628060/1997303 and try to adjust that to your needs.