# How we load all classes that placed in different directory in one PHP File

Tags: php, css, class

How we load all classes that placed in different directory in one PHP File , 
**means how to do auto load classes**

Comment: This is already extensively documented [in PHP's docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: How is this related to CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name your classes so the underscore (_) translates to the directory separator (/). A few PHP frameworks do this, such as Zend and Kohana.

So, you name your class Model_Article and place the file in classes/model/article.php and then your autoload does...

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    $filename = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class_name)).'.php';

    $file = AP_SITE.$filename;

    if ( ! file_exists($file))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    include $file;
}
```

Example taken from [Autoload classes from different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280347/autoload-classes-from-different-folders)

**Edit#1 Not Tested**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) { 

     $filename = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, strtolower($class_name)).'.php';

    $file = AP_SITE.$filename;

    if ( ! file_exists($file))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    include $file;
      });
```

Comment: `<?php spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) { include $class_name . '.php'; }); $obj = new MyClass1(); $obj2 = new MyClass2(); ?>` can we load class like this?

Comment: Also note you can use spl_autoload_register() to make any function an autoloading function. It is also more flexible, allowing you to define multiple autoload type functions. Please refer to the link

Comment: Okay Thank You for your Help... :)

Comment: Yes I seen. Thank You For Your Help Sir. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use ps4 and composer autoloader: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"My_Name_Space\\": "My_Folder/"}
    }
}
```

Then run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: `<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>`
can we load class like this?

Comment: Thank You for your Help... :)

Comment: Yes you can use simply the function spl_autoload_register() to autoload classes

Comment: Okay Thank You Sir for helping me. :)